# Geolocation HTML5 enableHighAccuracy True , False or Best Option?

Tags: html, geolocation

i have a problem about HTML5 geolocation feature. I use the code below to get location data. I use "enableHighAccuracy: false" option to work with Cell Based GPS feature. Accurancy is low but response it too fast. But some people always use Built-in GPS with their mobile phone, so this code does not work for them. Bu if i change accurency option as "enableHighAccuracy: true" it works for them. But this time, the code uses only built-in GPS. not CELL based GPS.

The question -> How can i do that : First, try to get position from Built-in GPS with timeout (e.g. 5000ms ) if position cannot be got in this time just look for Cell Based position for timeout (e.g. 10000ms) if position cannot be get in this time, return an error message .

Here is the code that i use now.

Thanks in advance.

```
    function getLocationfromGoogle() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function(pos) {
        $("#lat_field").val(pos.coords.latitude);
        $("#long_field").val(pos.coords.longitude);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
              geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latLng}, function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                //console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                $("#adresim").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                }
                else {
            alert('Google convertion is not succesfully done.');  

            }
            });
      },function error(msg){

                alert('Please enable your GPS position future.');  

      },{maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: false}

    ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should also be aware that the implementation of this varies from phone OS to phone OS - what works on Android may or may not work on iOS, BlackBerry, WindowsPhone, etc.

You're almost there, you just need to:

1. Specify `enableHighAccuracy: true` (you have it set to `false`)
2. Handle the timeout error case in the error handler. If the error from the high accuracy query is timeout, then try it again with `enableHighAccuracy: false`.

Have a look at this [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/CvSW4/761/).

You should also note that when testing this on a few devices, it returns location derived from WiFi even when `enableHighAccuracy: true`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CvSW4/761/ replaced position object with error object in error handling

Answer (score 7):

The code mentioned here: http://jsfiddle.net/CvSW4/ did not work for me during error handling.

The reason is that the error functions accept a parameter named 'position' but use an object in the functions called 'error'.

```
function errorCallback_highAccuracy(position) { ... }
function errorCallback_lowAccuracy(position) { ... }
```

The solution to fix this was to switch the error methods to accept the input value as a parameter named 'error' and not 'position', since the error callbacks do not accept a position and throw an error object instead.

```
function errorCallback_highAccuracy(error) { ... }
function errorCallback_lowAccuracy(error) { ... }
```

I mention it here, because I could not post on the resulting example page and also, this is the location where I linked through to find the code sample mentioned above.

Comment: Is this root problem still existing ? I couldn't recreate this issue