# High accuracy geolocation Html5

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am tring to locate a device using the embedded GPS (like whats app share location). I've read that it is possible with `enableHighAccuracy: true`.

How can I set `enableHighAccuracy: true` in this code? I tried in different positions but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var capa = document.getElementById("capa");
            capa.innerHTML = "latitude: " + latitude + ", longitude: " + ", accuracy: " + accuracy;  

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,
                title: "ok"
            });
        });

    } else {
        alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need a `PositionOptions` object, in which you set the high accuracy flag following the API.

I am quoting from here: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

> The getCurrentPosition() function has an optional third argument, a
>   PositionOptions object. There are three properties you can set in a
>   PositionOptions object. All the properties are optional. You can set
>   any or all or none of them.

```
POSITIONOPTIONS OBJECT

Property            Type        Default         Notes
--------------------------------------------------------------
enableHighAccuracy  Boolean     false           true might be slower
timeout             long        (no default)    in milliseconds
maximumAge          long        0               in milliseconds
```

So, it should work like this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var capa = document.getElementById("capa");
        capa.innerHTML = "latitude: " + latitude + ", longitude: " + ", accuracy: " + accuracy;

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coords,
            map: map,
            title: "ok"
        });

    },
    function error(msg) {alert('Please enable your GPS position feature.');},
    {maximumAge:10000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
} else {
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
}
```

Noticed I added the following 2 parameters to `getCurrentPosition` call:

1. `function error(msg){alert('Please enable your GPS position future.');}`

   This function is called when GPS could not be retrieved or the timeout has been triggered.
2. `{maximumAge:10000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});`

   These are the options. We don't want gps data that is older than 10 seconds (`maximumAge:10000`). We don't want to wait longer than 5 seconds for a response (`timeout:5000`) and we want to enable high accuracy (`enableHighAccuracy: true`).

Also see: [Geolocation HTML5 enableHighAccuracy True , False or Best Option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053262/geolocation-html5-enablehighaccuracy-true-false-or-best-option)

Comment: Thanks!! However, I can't get less than 65 meters accuracy :(

Comment: @meework You have set the enableHighAccuracy false instead of setting it true.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple example of `enableHighAccuracy: true` taken from the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Example).

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
       do_whatever_you_want
},
error => console.log(error),
{enableHighAccuracy: true}
)
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**
First of all, i am checking if the browser supports the geolocation using the `if` conditional on the top and wrapping whole code in it. If it exists then i try to get `getCurrentPosition` which returhs an object containing some info like the coordinates.I call that object `position`.
So if you want to get the `lat` and `lng`;

```
var lt = position.coords.latitude;
var ln = position.coords.longitude;
```

`GetCurrentPosition` takes some more arguments also. As first one was if it ran successfully(then i tried to get the returned object). The second one is the `error`. I console logged the error here. Third one is the extra options. One of those options is `enableHighAccuracy`. If set to `true` it will try to get the most accurate location from the user.

Comment: please some explain of your answer

Comment: didnt work for me. Shows the same presizenees as if i use it w/o enableHighAccuracy: true expression

Comment: Can you please share the details about your device which you are using.