# PhoneGap 3.3, IOS geolocation accuracy always 65

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

I create a PhoneGap application, using geolocation. I use the method watchPosition like this one:

```
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess, [geolocationError], [geolocationOptions]);
```

My problem is with the accuracy IOS returned is always 65 meters, while with the Android accuracy is variable and correct.

Do you have an idea of ​​where it may come?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5

Comment: I use enableHighAccuracy option. With android, the geolocation behaves correctly. My problem is only with IOS where accuracy is still 65 meters.

Comment: Is it possible that this is done at the I do not have a SIM card in the iPhone?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know and did not find the answer or more helpful items

Comment: I'll go get a SIM card. I hope that's it.. I'll let you know.

Comment: Same problem with a SIM card...

Comment: Maybe add the detailed code around the call (the options, etc.) to help someone to find an idea

Comment: Mmm... the SIM card is not valid, I do not have DATAS. I see the accuracy of google map native app is 65 meters too... I'll let you know... :p

Comment: Ok with a good SIM and DATAS, the accuracy is more than 65 meters but always 1414 meters. I am looking for a solution ... If I find anything,  I will add more information. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that it takes a SIM card connected to the wireless network.

Apparently, when the device has a wireless connection is always accuracy of 65 meters.

:)

Comment: So with the valid sim card you get better accuracy than 65? I have ipad with no sim card, use gps and have wifi connected and 65 meters is the max :-(