# How do you get your location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm trying to create a weather app, that will tell me the weather. How do I make a JSON request to get the coordinates of where I currently am?

Comment: JavaScript will not find your location. You need to use a Geo IP service. Try Google 'geolocation api free'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High accuracy geolocation Html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```