# Google not revert currect lattitude and longitude of current position

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, google-geocoder

I want to build locate me functionality in laravel. I am using this code but it is sending slightly different latitude and longitude.

```
function getLocation() 
{
  var x = document.getElementById("lat_long");
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
  x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) 
{
   var x = document.getElementById("lat_long");
   x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
   "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

Is there any alternate. so that i can improve my result.

Comment: This is Javascript not PHP/Laravel

Comment: yes, But i am using this is laravel php framework

Comment: Browser geolocation accuracy depends on a lot of factors. It will often not be exactly on point, that's expected.

Comment: PHP/Laravel has nothing to do with your question. You have used wrong tags, and you will receive less help.

Comment: See here: https://www.storelocatorwidgets.com/blogpost/20453/Everything_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_HTML5_Geolocation_Accuracy

Comment: Now javascript tag is added please try to solve my problem

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5 and read about the `EnableHighAccuracy` flag. But other than that, you don't have any problem, at least none that you've indicated. Geolocation isn't always completely accurate, especially on a desktop where you don't have GPS (like you would on a phone). There's nothing to solve here.

Comment: Then how shopping sites locate me correct address.

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? If you are on a smartphone, it'll be GPS based and highly accurate. If on a computer, much less accurate because GPS isn't available. Take a moment to first understand how browser geolocation works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order, for more accuracy you need to set Options object with enableHighAccuracy true. For more detail about the function you can check on this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
 console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```