# Geolocation API gives me wrong locations

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geolocation, frontend, location

I started to build a project, that has a map of where the uses are living and it can help them to set workouts places, pretty simple, you can see the demo right [here](https://mapty.netlify.app/). I used Geolocation API and [Leaflet library](https://leafletjs.com/) to make it.

And some beginning days, it displayed correctly the city where im living, but a few days ago, when I open it, it gives me wrong location, wrong city, which is about 90km away from my city. And today, I got a second wrong location, which is more 300km away.

I checked on other browser and it also has the same problems. I used my phone to check the location, it appears very true, even my phone and my computer use the same Wifi.

Please help me, i know that this question asked many times on Stack Overflow, but i didn't get helped. Im not sure if im undercontrolled by hackers or not, your answers are very important to me, thank you very very much readers.

Comment: Only use mobile data not wifi when testing. You have Wifi data from the operator, you have a dynamic IP so now you have 300km. You are now connecting to another server. In some time your IP will change again and you will land in some other place again :) If you want to test the application on a desktop browser, you can rigidly set its coordinates in the browser.

Comment: So its not weird when i have these problems, right? thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is.

When asking a Geolocation on a computer it is going to be less accurate. Your smartphone has more sensors and GPS. It will give a more accurate location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5

Comment: I want to know why the geolocation give me wrong locations on computer, not even one, it gave me wrong twice.

Comment: well, it gave me a location which is 300km away from my current city, is that strange? Or it is just because when asking a Geolocation on a computer it is going to be less accurate like you said? Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: It's not strange, because it's highly inaccurate.