# Accuracy Discrepancy between Google Maps and Google Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I found a lot of treatment of geolocation accuracy, but nothing that addresses the difference between the Google API and Maps. This is on Android Chrome.

Indeed, there's a large discrepancy between the two. The API gives me 30 meters at best, but Maps manages less than 10. What gives? Here are snippets from my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>
```

Then later:

```
function getLoc() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLoc, errorLoc,
  {maximumAge:15000, timeout:60000, enableHighAccuracy:true});
}

function showLoc(position) {
 var elt = document.getElementById("userloc");
 elt.innerHTML = "Lat " + position.coords.latitude + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                 "Long " + position.coords.longitude + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                 "Accuracy " + position.coords.accuracy;
}

function errorLoc(msg) {
 alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's may because you've only taken one geoloc sample.  The gps hardware is cold, and the accuracy result google gives you is based on how many other samples it's received in a certain span of time.

Take a lot of samples in a short span, and see if you can notice a difference.  Then pick whatever you think gives you the best tradeoff between accuracy, time to sample, and battery consumption.

It's not uncommon to see the reported accuracy within 3-5m when you poll over 5 seconds.  That's not its true accuracy though, just the data consistency.  Things like buildings, walls, can skew results (time it takes for frequency to travel though) without necessarily affecting reported accuracy (apparent consistency of the data).

If you get 30m consistently btw (as in it doesn't fluctuate at all), it might be because the gps hardware is disabled, and it's using wifi internet address lookups as a backup.

Comment: OK cool. I am getting 30 consistently, with coordinates that don't change between polls. Is there a way to check if GPS is on? I assume Maps is using it. How do I use it?

Comment: The return object unfortunately doesn't appear to identify the source of the readings.  Some of the lower lvl API's do.  When I run my app, the device's geoloc icon pulses, to indicate it's reading.  If you fail to see that, it's a sign the hardware isn't being used.  The "enableHighAccuracy" is only defined as a  hint for this particular API, the implementation need not actually honor it, and user settings for the device can override it (make sure device settings are enabled and you have permissions).  http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#high-accuracy

Comment: Might be useful link for you to problem solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053262/geolocation-html5-enablehighaccuracy-true-false-or-best-option

Comment: I switched my phone from "High accuracy" to "Device only" and now I'm getting better results; not much, but better. I don't see the geolocation icon either way, not the one I see when using Maps.