# How can i know the location of a user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I try to detect the exact location of user and specially the street if i can.

I tried that using the **IP** but this didn't work for me because it didn't give the exact location example for what i want is **Lebanon Beirut Azarieh or Lebanon Beirut ABC Achrafieh**   and than i want to store this location in **MYSQL** database table using **PHP**.

i tried this code [here](http://www.codexworld.com/get-visitor-location-using-html5-geolocation-api-php/)
this code give a good location in Firefox on Localhost

but Online on Firefox and Google chrome give me that Your Location: Not Available

also it didn't work on phone browser iPhone and android (safari,chrome,...)

the idea is a user in the company want to use the website on his phone a special page on the website when he use it i want to take here exact location with the street and store this in database

Comment: IP Geo data is a rough estimate and some IP Geo records are not accurate. To get an exact/more accurate  location this will require GPS permission so the client will have to allow/gran your site/application permission to use the clients GPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag, `enableHighAccuracy:true`

Here's an example code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
          //alert('latitude: '+latitude+' longitude: '+longitude);
      }, function(error) {
          alert('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
      },{timeout:20000,enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
  else{
    alert('no geolocation support');
  }
});
```

And I also want to quote that `enableHighAccuracy` depends from device to device.

reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056940/1681154)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an android code link,you can get some idea from.[getlocation with street](http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/)

Comment: but it's not an aplication this is a website